# Can I modify the Javascript section of a PDF with javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

PDF has a tool called Javascript, where you can add some script to the pdf and add some functionality o variable text.

[PDF tools - Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MERfl.png)

Is there a way where I can open that pdf through javascript and edit that part of the pdf and then save it as a new pdf?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can open any file in the browser (as long as the user selects it), read the data, edit the data and download the edited data back to the hard disk (as long as the user clicks on the download link)

So, answer to your question is theoretically yes.

However, to edit a particular section of a PDF, you need to first understand the PDF file format. If you can interpret the PDF data yourself and change the section you are looking to, this can be done.

One other way around understanding the PDF file format is using a library. The following library seems to be capable of editing the PDF too.

https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows the Acrobat Pro tools so the answer is Yes though not all PDF editors can do that.

To add or replace JavaScript at the document level that runs when the file is opened use the doc Object addScript method.

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2FDoc_methods.htm%23TOC_addScriptbc-7&rhtocid=_6_1_8_23_1_6

You can also add or replace JavaScript associated with different objects and events using setAction

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2FDoc_methods.htm%23TOC_addScriptbc-7&rhtocid=_6_1_8_23_1_6